# How could one efficiently check for a 401 response from a URL in C#?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I would like to create a method that determines if a particular URL is available anonymously. I'm doing this in order to strip out inaccessible results from a custom search page. The best I can come up with is

```
    public bool IsWebAddressAccessible(string Url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

However, this is less than ideal for a few two reasons. Firstly, as I understand, it's not efficient to rely on exceptions for logic in this way. Secondly, in the case where the page is accessible, it seems to retrieve the whole page, which is time-consuming. So the questions are:

1. Is there a way to do this without relying on exceptions?
2. Is there a way to speed this up so I can just see whether the response is coming back as 401 or not without waiting to retrieve the entire page?

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to use built-in .NET classes for handling HTTP where possible, so you retain the automatic use of IE proxy settings, etc?  Is it just a regular request, no cookies, no POST data etc?

Comment: It's just a basic request using current proxy settings. Nothing special is being sent in the request. All I want to do is see if the response returns a 401 vs. page data.

Answer (score 1):

1. this is a [vexing exception](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) in the design of HttpWebRequest. I've actually got a couple of extension methods in one of my projects (one that makes a lot of requests that are expected to return 304 not modified):

   ```
   [DebuggerNonUserCode]
   public static HttpWebResponse GetHttpResponse(this HttpWebRequest request) {
       // We know the response will be a HttpWebResponse because the request is a HttpWebRequest
       return (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
   }

   [DebuggerNonUserCode]
   public static HttpWebResponse GetHttpResponseAvoidVexingExceptions(this HttpWebRequest request) {
       try {
           return GetHttpResponse(request);
       } catch (WebException ex) {
           HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
           switch (response.StatusCode) {
               case HttpStatusCode.NotModified:
                   return response;

               default:
                   // We don't catch other exceptions
                   throw;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   There's no way I'm aware of to avoid this exception.
2. Like Mark said, use the `HEAD` method to only get back the response headers.

Comment: Note: `DebuggerNonUserCode` is used here so that if an exception is thrown, the debugger will break in a useful place, i.e. where the request is being made, and not in a helper method